# stopping vim from removing indentation on empty lines

Tags: vim, indentation

When the cursor is placed at the end of a line containing nothing but withspace characters, vim will, when i press enter, remove that whitespace. I find this irritating, as it breaks my script for selecting code that are indented to the same level. How can I prevent vim from doing this?

In my .vimrc (http://bjuhn.com/randomstuff/vimrc) I have the following:

```
filetype plugin on
set copyindent
```

that is, I am not using any syntax-aware auto-indention, as I have yet to find one that does everything to my liking.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The [Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Get_the_correct_indent_for_new_lines_despite_blank_lines) suggests this:

```
inoremap <CR> <CR>x<BS>
```

because the indenting is not removed if some text has been entered on the line, even if it has been deleted.

**[EDIT - milimetric]**

Just a couple of pieces missing from a full solution.  You also need remaps for o and O and whatever else you use to add lines:

```
inoremap <CR> <CR>x<BS>
nnoremap o ox<BS>
nnoremap O Ox<BS>
```

Same idea but people newer to vim might not figure it out quickly.

Comment: I agree, but it seems to be safe enough.

Comment: If you want to enable this behaviour for certain file types only (e.g. Python files) remember the "autocmd FileType" command. For example "autocmd FileType python inoremap <CR> <CR>x<BS>" did what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

For me this code works:

```
inoremap <silent> <Esc> <C-O>:stopinsert<CR>
```

Comment: What does which part mean and do?