# Vim Pre-Exit (Esc Key) Command?

Tags: vim, indentation, esc-key

Right now in Vim when I go to a new line (or press 'p' or 'o' in normal mode) I get a lovely automatic indent, that also disappears if I exit insert mode without adding anything to it.

Is there a way to bind something to before I exit insert mode, such as inserting a phantom character then removing it?

Comment: See also "[stopping vim from removing indentation on empty lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413036/stopping-vim-from-removing-indentation-on-empty-lines)".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Argh, I just read about this exact thing like two days ago but I can't remember where.

Anyway, the trick is to input a character right after `<CR>` and delete it immediately. There are a bunch of ways to do it:

```
<CR>a<Esc>x
<CR>a<C-w>
<CR>a<BS>
```

`--EDIT--`

Vim being Vim there are probably many other ways.

To automate these, you need to add a mapping to your .vimrc:

```
inoremap <CR> <CR>a<BS> " insert mode mapping for <CR>
nnoremap o oa<BS>       " normal mode mapping for o
```

But I'm not sure you should overwrite defaults like that.

`--EDIT--`

However, what is annoying with Vim's default behaviour is that you may need to do some `<Tab><Tab><Tab><Tab>` before actually inputing some text on non-indented line or do `==` when you are done or rely on the automatic indentation rules for your language at the next `<CR>`.

All that can be skipped by using `<S-S>` which puts you in INSERT mode right at the correct indentation level.

Comment: Oddly when pressing Esc Vim still removes the whitespace, this also doesn't work when using 'p' or 'o' to enter insert mode.

Comment: `p` stands for "put", you don't go in INSERT mode after a `p`. Did you try all three of my propositions? Did you try `<S-s>`? Also why do you `<Esc>` after `o`? If you want a blank line to separate code blocks the presence/absence of white space at the beginning of the line doesn't really matter, does it? Are you sure `oa<BS>` doesn't work in that usecase? What are your settings if any for `tabstop`, `softtabstop`, `expandtab`, `shiftwidth`, `shiftround` and `smarttab`?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how to use your propositions. Adding a character then removing it works, but I'm not sure how I'd automate it.

Answer (score 2):

Try either `cc` or `S` in normal mode to change a line with respect to indention. No need for phantom characters.

```
:h cc
:h S
```

Comment: I back this up.  Do not try to overcome the normal Vim behavior which is not accidental.  Usually, lines containing only whitespace (which are a special case of lines with trailing whitespace) are undesired in code (for example, Linux coding style [notices to avoid this](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/Documentation/CodingStyle#L222)).

Comment: It seems to me to just lack consistency rather than be good practice. Is there some paper showing the benefits?

Comment: Actually I agree with ib and Peter. Overwriting default behaviours is a bad idea in general if only because you may use someone else's or a stock/older vim on some server one day. Everything in Vim is carefully thought out and has been so since a long time. That's what I alluded to in my answer and comments.

Answer (score 1):

A mapping like the following should do the trick:

```
imap <esc> <esc>:s/\s\+$//<CR>
```

This one deletes trailing characters when you press <kbd>esc</kbd> in insert mode.

Comment: Ah. I kind of want the trailing characters.

Comment: The mapping I wrote for you is just an example. You could adapt it to your real needs

Comment: That's post-exit, not pre-exit though.

Comment: OK. It's an example. Just a way to show you how you can remap esc in order to do what you what. So it's "post-exit" because I wrote it in that way but if you want something else you could just modify the mapping ;)