# Vim: Persistent Indentation

Tags: vim, autocomplete, auto-indent, tabstop

I have `set smartindent` in my Vim configuration file, but there is one aspect of automatic tab insertion in Vim that I would like to modify. Say, for example, that I begin typing a for-loop:

```
1. for (auto& foo : bar) {
2.
```

After I hit return, Vim kindly inserts a tab at the beginning of line 2, exactly how I want it. But if realize that I need to jump somewhere else in the file to modify something, and subsequently return to line 2, the tab is no longer there. Hitting tab a couple of times every now and then isn't a big deal, with when I'm writing a complicated algorithm with lots of indentation, having to mash the tab key several times can get frustrating.

What would be the best solution to make Vim actually *write* a tab into the current buffer when doing automatic indentation, instead of only giving me the opportunity to insert the tab when I hit return from the previous line?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: This was discussed many times in many places. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7413036/557306) question, it might help you.

Comment: The problem with the hack suggested by the accepted answer is that when I type '}', the indentation doesn't automatically shift left by one unit. Also, using `cc` or `S` on the empty line in which the indentation disappears still puts me at the very beginning of the line.

Comment: There's a good chance you would have better results by using `filetype indent on` rather than using `smartindent`.  `cc` and `S` should work in that case.  From the #vim help channel on freenode: "Don't you mean stupidindent? In all seriousness, 'smartindent' is an obsolete option for C-like syntax. It has been replaced with 'cindent', and setting 'cindent' also overrides 'smartindent'. Vim has indentation support for many languages out-of-the-box, and setting 'smartindent' (or 'cindent', for that matter) in your .vimrc might interfere with this. Use 'filetype plugin indent on' and be happy."

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an intentionally designed behavior.  When user jump away then move back to the old place (`Line 2`), the `original tabs` lost.  *Instead of moving to Line 2*, user can move to `Line 1`, and press **o**, user get auto-indented **new Line 2**.  At the same time, user can use all power Vim offers to `map` or even `vimscript` a new way to keep the `old tabs`. By this, I admire Vi/Vim's design.

In short, when jumped back to `Line: 1.`, press **o**.  `New indented Line 2.` appears.