# Prevent removal of indentation upon return to normal mode in Vim

Tags: vim, auto-indent

I have :set autoindent in my .vimrc. So if I have the following:

```
    foo bar baz|
```

where the pipe character is my cursor in insert mode, and I press return, it would be as though I were using notepad, and had pressed `<return><tab>`. In other words, it would automatically carry my indentation scheme from the last line to the new one. This is great, actually all I want to have happen. If I type a `word` after pressing return and then leave insert mode, then that is just what happens. However, if I were to skip typing the `word`, and directly exited insert mode by pressing `Esc`, the indentation would be removed, so if I were to subsequently reenter insert mode (to account for notepad's lack of normal mode), it would be as though I were using notepad and simply pressed return.

Does anyone have an idea of how I can disable this "litter disposal" mechanism of Vim? I can see why it's there, because many times one wouldn't want to have an empty line that appears visibly empty, but is in fact littered with invisible whitespace characters. But in this case I really just want vim to do what I say, exactly, and not try to guess what I want or mean. How can I have that?

Thanks

Comment: So you don't care about having trailing white space in your files?

Comment: Yes. Indeed, I need it there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [stopping vim from removing indentation on empty lines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7413036/stopping-vim-from-removing-indentation-on-empty-lines)